# Can you add CSS style to Photoshop layers?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Has anybody tried to apply CSS style to Photoshop layers? If yes, could you please share the method. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Adobe Fireworks would be the program you want to work with if you're looking for CSS support.